# Javascript check if a function has been created on other file

Tags: javascript

Hey i am creating a DOM javascript library and i found myself having the following problem:

For example, if i take a function lets say `function update()` how can i check if this function has been created on another file; If it has been created on another file how can I make it run once or every couple of seconds without the user need to do this?

For example in the library [p5.js](https://p5js.org/) :

```
//If this function has created on this file it will run every one second
function update(){

}
```

&&

```
//if this function has created on this file it will call itself once the page is loaded
function start(){

}
```

*Edit: tried to be more clear on my question thank you for your answers!

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` endlessly within the function.. but I think your question is a candidate for being closed because it's extremely vague. especially the title..

Comment: Why would you not use setInterval?

Comment: `setInterval` serves exactly this purpose. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: I want to create a library that everytime this function like this is called it can be repeat itself instead of letting the user to do so by himself @Al.G.

Comment: @vsync I wasn't really sure on how to ask it to be honest with you...

Comment: The user doesn't need to call `setInterval`, the function can call `setInterval` by itself with an inner anonymous function.

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean by "inner anonymous function" do you have any code example for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimeout(func, 1000)` will call `func` 1000 milliseconds later.

If you wanted your function to call immediately, you could do a recursion (bad way, better use a loop, but it's useful to illustrate the next example):

```
// calls itself infinitely, without any delay
function update(){
  update(); // Will cause a stack overflow, infinitely deep recursion
}
```

Now you can make use of `setTimeout` and tell `update` to run a second later.

```
// calls itself infinitely, 1 second delay between calls
function update(){
  setTimeout(update, 1000);
}
```

There is no recursion here. Instead, you defer the call to `update()` for one second. The second time `update()` is called, another `setTimeout` will be called, and so on infinitely.

The second part of your question:

```
//call itself once the page is loaded
function start(){
}
```

You can set an event listener to when the page is loaded, and call that function:

```
window.addEventListener('load', start);
```

Do this right after defining `start()`.

---

To reflect your comment:

If you want to detect if the global function `update` has been defined (by the user, probably) and want to start calling it automatically on equal intervals of 1 second, you'll need to check its existance with `typeof` and then apply `setInterval` on it:

```
if(typeof update === "function") {
  setInterval(update, 1000);
}
```

To make it explicit that you're refering to a global `update` and not a local variable, you can use `window.update` instead. In that case, you could also check if it exists this way:

```
if(update in window)
```

Comment: For the first part, I mostly meant if there is any way that if the user creates a function that called "update" a script will automatically set an Interval of 1 second for this function.
And the second part has set me up with the solution of start() thank you!

Comment: @Ran edited my answer with a solution to your clarified problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Next time try to be as much as clear and explicit as possible, for quicker and more positive responses :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the user needing to call `setInterval()` to repeat `update()`, it can call it itself.

```
function update() {
    setInterval(function() {
        // do something
    }, 1000);
}
```

All the actual work that needs to be done goes where `// do something` is.